# Deploy custom Lightning App Home Page assignment using SalesforceDX

Tags: salesforcedx, lightning-apps

Which is the metadata responsible for specify the assignment of a custom lightning app home page to a lightning app?

In my lightning app metadata I just have the specification of the home page tab:

```
<CustomApplication xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <brand>
        <headerColor>#0070D2</headerColor>
        <shouldOverrideOrgTheme>false</shouldOverrideOrgTheme>
    </brand>
    <formFactors>Small</formFactors>
    <formFactors>Large</formFactors>
    <isNavAutoTempTabsDisabled>true</isNavAutoTempTabsDisabled>
    <isNavPersonalizationDisabled>true</isNavPersonalizationDisabled>
    <label>Finances</label>
    <navType>Standard</navType>
    <tabs>standard-home</tabs>
    <uiType>Lightning</uiType>
    <utilityBar>Finances_UtilityBar</utilityBar>
</CustomApplication>
```

Every time I deploy my project, I have to manually activate my custom lightning home page to my custom app.
How do I do to deploy my custom app with the custom lightning home page already activated?

**FURTHER INFO**

profileActionOverrides only works for changeSets. I am deploying using an Unlocked Package.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ProfileActionOverride](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profileactionoverride.htm) along with your custom application metadata.Something like below should help

```
<CustomApplication xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<brand>
    <headerColor>#0070D2</headerColor>
    <shouldOverrideOrgTheme>false</shouldOverrideOrgTheme>
</brand>
<formFactors>Small</formFactors>
<formFactors>Large</formFactors>
<isNavAutoTempTabsDisabled>true</isNavAutoTempTabsDisabled>
<isNavPersonalizationDisabled>true</isNavPersonalizationDisabled>
<label>Finances</label>
<navType>Standard</navType>
<tabs>standard-home</tabs>
<uiType>Lightning</uiType>
<utilityBar>Finances_UtilityBar</utilityBar>
<profileActionOverrides>
    <actionName>Tab</actionName>
    <content>CustomObjectFlexiPage</content>
    <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
    <pageOrSobjectType>standard-home</pageOrSobjectType>
    <type>Flexipage</type>
    <profile>standard</profile>
    <recordType>null</recordType>
</profileActionOverrides>
```

Note on packaging - Note that profile overrides are not supported in packaging .You will need to use mdapi commands after you deploy the unlocked packages to activate this.

Comment: thank you man but it didn't work :/

Comment: Actually just read my use case is not supported by  ProfileActionOverride: I'm deploying the app using an Unlocked Package ....

Comment: Yes unlocked package this might not be supported. This is applicable only for changesets and deploy via mdapi